# UTF-8 text to clipboard C

Tags: c, windows, unicode, utf-8, clipboard

I have been looking around on how to bring a string,

```
const char* output = "ヽ(⌐■_■)ノ♪♬";
```

to the clipboard.

```
SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hMem);
```

I have tried MultiByteToWideChar, but I have gotten only noise and also conflicting claims that you cannot save UTF-16LE to clipboard (wchar_t). Honestly I am just confused. A direction or code sample would be great.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Adrian: `MultiByteToWideChar` is a Windows AP, so Windows.

Comment: This is pretty easy in SDL if you decide to use that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows uses UTF-16LE. The string should be created with `L` prefix. To use UTF8 you can declare the string with `u8` prefix. For example:

```
const char* text = u8"ヽ(⌐■_■)ノ♪♬E";
```

Then you have to use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert UTF8 to UTF16 and use in WinAPI. Note that to use `u8` you need newer compilers like VS2015.

It's easier to use UTF16 in the first place. For example:

```
const wchar_t* text = L"ヽ(⌐■_■)ノ♪♬E";
int len = wcslen(text);

HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, (len + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
wchar_t* buffer = (wchar_t*)GlobalLock(hMem);
wcscpy_s(buffer, len + 1, text);
GlobalUnlock(hMem);

OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hMem);
CloseClipboard();
```