# C++ win32 How do I make a password field selectable and enable copying and pasting?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017, desktop-application

So I'm currently in need of a password field, for displaying already known password. But since I don't want to directly show the password to the user, I have decided to use a password field instead of a normal field. Since the program itself is working I will only show the code where I create the edit field, since that's the only place I will make changes to it based on the requirements of this program.

This is the code snippet of my edit box

```
std::wstring password = account.GetPassW();
HWND hWndEditPassword = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), 
    password.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_PASSWORD, 85, 30, 245,
    20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL
);
```

account is a variable of type `struct UserAccount` and `GetPassW()` is a function which converts from `std::string` to `std::wstring` since the strings are originally loaded and stored as those first ones.

This code works fine if it was a normal login form, but this is not a login form, this is a login recovery form, where the password field shows asterisks (*) for security reasons. And this password field has to be support selecting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and copy pasting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> which doesn't seem to be the case with the default password field with this setting.

Again like I said. This is not a program for logging in to something. This is a program where you select a platform or similar, and this window pops up with your stored username and password, already filled into the input boxes, ready to be copy pasted into respective program. The problem is since I'm using `ES_PASSWORD` for the password box, it automatically makes the edit box unable to select and copy which would not work with the intention of this program. So I need to find a way to enable those features of an edit box while keeping the asterisk stuff.

How would I get along doing this?
*Would really appreciate some code to illustrate the solution.*

Comment: You do realize that anybody can then copy/paste the password into NotePad, say, as plain text, right?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Considering this is meant to be an account recovery for your own accounts that's not really a problem here. The password field is just in case someone would see your screen when you use it (either by you streaming the screen or just simply looking at it), you know, common sense when dealing with passwords.
Edit: As I said, you are meant to be copying from this password field in the first place. It's just hidden in case someone else would see your screen.

Comment: One easy solution would be to put a button next to the field which copies its contents to the clipboard.

Comment: You can toggle the password flag with `SendMessage(hedit, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, make_visible ? 0 : (WPARAM)L'*', 0)` this will show the password and enable copy. It's not safe, but copying the password in to clipboard is not safe either. The clipboard is available to all programs.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed so solve the problem. But the solution is more of a patch job than a direct solution, so I wouldn't say this answer would help other but it worked for me for what I intend to use it for.

So what I did was to keep it a password field, but I made a static variable

```
static WNDPROC wndProcPasswordOld;
static UserAccount currentAccount;
static HWND hWndEditPassword;
```

Then where I initialize the password box, I now have this

```
hWndEditPassword = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), password.c_str(),
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_PASSWORD | ES_READONLY, 85, 30, 245,
    20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
wndProcPasswordOld = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hWndEditPassword, GWLP_WNDPROC,
    (LONG_PTR)WndProcPassword);

// This is further down
currentAccount = account;
```

Then I have a `WNDPROC` named `WndProcPassword` forward declared and implemented at the bottom as follows

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcPassword(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if ((wParam == 'C' || wParam == 'c') && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)
        {
            std::string data = currentAccount.password;
            const char *output = data.c_str();
            const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
            HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
            memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            OpenClipboard(0);
            EmptyClipboard();
            SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
            CloseClipboard();
            break;
        }
        return CallWindowProc(wndProcPasswordOld, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    default:
        return CallWindowProc(wndProcPasswordOld, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This does however not remove the sound, but it's not big of a deal with how I intend using this program, but I decided to leave this answer since I couldn't find any other information on how to have an edit field copyable while still having the characters show asterisks.

**EDIT:**
I have now found a solution I find better than the above but I've decided to keep both.

The `WM_KEYDOWN` event in `WndProcPassword` has changed to `WM_KEYUP`.
Additionall in the if statement inside `WM_KEYUP` I'm also checking if the event is

```
if (((wParam == 'C' || wParam == 'c') && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) || (wParam == VK_CONTROL && (GetKeyState('C') & 0x8000 || GetKeyState('c') & 0x8000)))
{
    // copy to clipboard
}
```

I then went ahead and changed the creation of the box to

```
hWndEditPassword = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), L"",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY, 85, 30, 245,
    20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
SetEditText(password);
```

Where this `SetEditText` looks as follows

```
void SetEditText(std::wstring text)
{
    int buffersize = text.length() + 1;
    WCHAR *wchars = new WCHAR[buffersize];
    memset(wchars, 0, sizeof(WCHAR) * buffersize);
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        wchars[i] = L'*';

    SetWindowText(hWndEditPassword, wchars);

    delete[] wchars;
}
```

This change makes the control act as a normal edit box, only change is that when you set the text, you replace the input with asterisks manually, and since copying is done on key down, you simply add your own copying in the keyup event.
This also removes all limitations and error sounds when interacting with the input box.

Comment: To copy text with Unicode encoding see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759786/4603670)